# Outlook 2007 hangs on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-outlook-2007, freeze

Every now and then Outlook 2007 hangs on Windows 7 64-bit. I have not been able to find a set of reproduceable steps. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. It generally hangs while I'm busy doing something: writing a message, looking up an address, etc. It seems like it's a race condition that can be triggered by a large variety of input operations. Out of curiosity, are you using Outlook over RDP? I am, and maybe that's part of it.

Comment: I am not using RDP

Comment: I switched to Outlook 2010, and I do not get any more hangs. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I would check  your .pst file to see how large it is.  If it is 2GB or larger then you may want to create a 2nd .pst file and start migrating old emails over or delete emails you no longer need.  If it is not over 2GB then the .pst maybe corrupted and you should try scanpst on the file. Here is the link on how to run scanpst (Inbox Repair Tool) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287497

Answer (score 0):

I've found something as simple as a highly fragmented .pst file can cause severe slowdowns.  I'd close Outlook and degragment your hard drive or use `contig.exe` from the [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062).